# How to wirelessly stream from sensor such as Adafruit LIS3DH

Tags: sensor, wireless, accelerometer

I'm extremely new to electronics and with some help, I was able to identify an accelerometer (Adafruit LIS3DH) that matched my needs, but I have no clue how to stream data from it to my computer or anything else. I bought an Arduino and have a RPi already. What else would I need in order to be able to accomplish this? Is any tutorial you all would recommend that could help me with this or course I could take only. Even just a list of items would be greatly helpful. I've searched but can't seem to find anything wireless. Last thing, I need this to stay as small as possible.

Comment: rpi should itself be capable of wirelessly streaming.  break the task down.  start by reliably reading the sensor while it is wired.  designing filters for proper accelerometer reads is a big task!  once you read, it is a matter of streaming - look at serial to begin.  then you can look at tcp and network sockets (wifi) or bluetooth (serial over bt)

Comment: data streaming has nothing to do with the sensor ... the sensor is actually irrelevant to the question

Comment: There’s plenty of ready made boards to do what you want. Do you want WiFi or Bluetooth?

Comment: @Kartman really? I've asked around so many times and couldn't find any. Are they fairly small? I'd want whichever will use the least power.